# How to pass data when navigating through TabBar?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

To pass data beetwen viewmodels when navigating I use query parameters (IQueryAttributable), i.e.:

```
NavigationParameters[nameof(SomeProperty)] = SomeProperty;
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SomePage", NavigationParameters);
```

It works as it should be working, but I wish to put SomePage into a TabBar:

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Route="SomePage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SomePage}"/>
    ...
</TabBar>
```

Is there a way to pass data when user click/tap SomePage icon on the tab bar? Is there some event for that so I could hook up GoToAsync method? Or maybe there is another way than query to pass data beetwen viewmodels?

Comment: use MessagingCenter

Comment: You could also hold handles to other view models in your view model, like a common section that's shared between all your pages. Because really, you shouldn't need to pass data between view models like this, they should have access to any and all pertinent data at will.

Comment: Specifically in your tab bar layout, the tabs should work on the same view model (except for the settings tab, if you have it). The tabs are just different views in your same data.

Comment: @Blindy Now I'm really confused, because passing data is done as described in [MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data).
Regarding one viewmodel, it is funny beacuse that is the way I've designed my app at the beginning but then my senior collegue told me that each view should have it's own viewmodel... So I've redesigned application which brought me to this point where you're telling me it'a all wrong... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MauiProgram.cs:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>();
        builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<Page_1>
            .AddSingleton<ViewModel_1>
            .AddSingleton<Page_2>
            .AddSingleton<ViewModel_2>
            .AddSingleton<ISharedDataInterface, SharedDataInterfaceImplementation>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Page_1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page_1 : ContentPage
{
    public LogoPage(ViewModel_1 viewModel_1)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel_1;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Page_2.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page_2 : ContentPage
{
    public LogoPage(ViewModel_2 viewModel_2)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel_2;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel_1.cs:

```
public class ViewModel_1
{
    public ViewModel_1(ISharedDataInterface sharedDataInterfaceImplementation)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

ViewModel_2.cs:

```
public class ViewModel_2
{
    public ViewModel_2(ISharedDataInterface sharedDataInterfaceImplementation)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great approach! Please show how your xaml refers to those shared properties. Is it something like `{Binding Shared.SomeProperty}`?

Comment: Thanks:) 
In viewmodel you need to create public property: `ISharedDataInterface SharedDataInterfaceImplementation` and populate it with parameter passed in constructor: `SharedDataInterfaceImplementation = sharedDataInterfaceImplementanion`.
In xaml:
`{Binding SharedDataInterfaceImplementation.SomeProperty}`.
Don't forget about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in SharedDataInterfaceImplementation if the data will be updated during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If the two pages are in the same `Tab`,you can create a static global variable for the viewmodel in `App.xaml.cs`  and access this variable in your different pages.

For example,we can first define a view model (e.g. `TestViewModel.cs`):

```
   public class TestViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 

    public TestViewModel() {

        str = "123";
    }

    public  string _str;

    public  string str
    {
        get
        {
            return _str;
        }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And define a static global variable in App.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class App : Application
{

    public static TestViewModel testViewModel;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();

        testViewModel = new TestViewModel();

    }
}
```

Then , you can assgin the global variable for `BindingContext`  in different pages:

```
   public partial class Tab1 : ContentPage
   {
    public Tab1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = App.testViewModel;

    }
   }



  public partial class Tab2 : ContentPage
{
    public Tab2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = App.testViewModel;

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.testViewModel.str = "Test";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Meanwhile I've done my homework and solved the problem by adding services in app builder and registering singletons for data models I need to share beetwen viewmodels. I think that this is the proper way to handle such issues.

Answer (score 0):

*"You could also hold handles to other view models in your view model, like a common section that's shared between all your pages."*

That is the advice to follow.

Suppose each tab's viewmodel has `public MySharedType Shared { get; private set; }`,
and constructor is `MyTab1ViewModel(MySharedType shared) { this.Shared = shared; }`.

Then from xaml, access a shared property by: `{Binding Shared.MyProperty1}`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I've managed to solve the problem by my own in a different way:)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see a practical example.

You have one **TabbedPage** and two **ContentPage**. The idea is that you will pass the correct parameter when the user taps the specific tab. In this context you can pass any parameter on demand to your tab page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.TabPage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages">

    <pages:Page1/>

    <pages:Page2/>

</TabbedPage>
```

Add the bellow code to the TabbedPage code behind.

```
public TabPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.CurrentPageChanged += TabPage_CurrentPageChanged;
    PassParams();
}

private void TabPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PassParams();
}

private void PassParams()
{
   if (this.CurrentPage.GetType() == typeof(Page1))
   {
       Page1 cur = (Page1)this.CurrentPage;
       cur.Param1 = 123;
   }
   if (this.CurrentPage.GetType() == typeof(Page2))
   {
       Page2 cur = (Page2)this.CurrentPage;
       cur.Param2 = 456;
   }
}
```

Add the below to Page1 code behind. About the same code goes to Page2, just replace number 1.

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

int param1;
public int Param1
{
   set
   {
       param1 = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
       BindingContext = new Page1ViewModel(param1);
    }
}
```

The Page1ViewModel will have to handle the parameter.

```
public Page1ViewModel(int param1)
{
   //populate your view with your models
}
```